# Timeout in Elastic search query

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have following elastic search query, I want to apply timeout. So I used 
 "**timeout**" param.

```
GET testdata-2016.04.14/_search
{
  "size": 10000,
  "timeout": "1ms"
}
```

I have set timeout to be 1ms, but I observed that query is taking time about more than 5000ms. I have tried the query as below also:

```
GET testdata-2016.04.14/_search?timeout=1ms
{
  "size": 10000
}
```

IN both cases, I am getting below response after approx. 5000ms.

```
{
  "took": 126,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 26536,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
     {
       ...................
       ...................
     }
  }
}
```

I am not sure what is happening here. Is anything missing in above queries ?
 Please help.

I have tried to find out solution on google but didn't find any working solution.

Comment: Which version of ES are you using?

Comment: I am using 2.3.2 version.